# How to share text in Facebook Messenger in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-messenger

The below link says sharing images, animated gifs, videos and audio clips to Messenger

[Facebook Messenger](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios)

How to share text in Facebook Messenger?

Comment: have to get any solution? Is it possible to share simple text or links?